# Google cloud endpoints HTTP 500 error on delete

Tags: google-app-engine, internal-server-error, google-cloud-endpoints

Google cloud endpoints HTTP 500 error on delete

I generated a Google Cloud Endpoint class which game me the standard CRUD methods including the delete method:

```
public Member removeMember(@Named("id") Long id) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    Member member = null;
    try {
        member = mgr.getObjectById(Member.class, id);
        mgr.deletePersistent(member);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return member;
}
```

However when I invoke a DELETE I get a HTTP 500 error returned:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /_ah/spi/Members.removeMember. Reason:

com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Cannot read fields from a deleted object (through reference chain: com.mylodge.contracts.masonry.Member[\"degree\"])
```

How can I avoid this HTTP 500 error?

Aside: To me it seems illogical to return the deleted object anyway. Wouldn't a HTTP 200 OK be more appropriate?

**UPDATE:** I have tried return null instead, and tried making the method a VOID. But both of these yield an HTTP response of

```
500 No content to map to Object due to end of input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the object, don't return it. That's the easiest solution here. I'm going to suggest to the Google Plugin for Eclipse team that they change the template to *not* return the deleted object by default.

If you do want the deleted object, I think you're running into JDO's lazy loading. Your property `degree` is being loaded at serialization time. However, since the underlying datastore object is already deleted, it can't access it. You'll need to explicitly access the property before it gets deleted.

Comment: If I instead return null OR I change the method to a VOID, the resulting HTTP response is a "500 No content to map to Object due to end of input" I really just want to return an HTTP 200 - ideally with no content.

Comment: Did you regenerate your client library after this?

Comment: I'm not using a client library - I'm simply invoking an HTTP DELETE request using Fidder - I'm just writing the server side API.

Comment: There appears to be an error in the dev appserver. I see a `204 No Content` in production, but the same error you report in the dev appserver.

Comment: This should be fixed in the 1.7.7 release (including the pre-release SDK that's available now: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/detail?name=appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7_prerelease.zip)

Comment: Thanks for investigating Dan. When can we expect the 1.7.7 final release?

Comment: Hi Dan What is the issue number on the defect list on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list I would like to follow the progress

Comment: It's not listed there as it was discovered and fixed by the team before you and I discovered it. I can't give you an exact date, but I would expect it soon. :)